# Solidity Remix - Failed Transaction on main chain, but working on private and alternate chains

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, remix

I have a deployed contract, with a function to release the balance of the contract to the owner. I have tested this on Ethereum clone chains and everything was working fine as expected. However, when I've deployed the contract on Ethereum main chain, I get failed transactions when invoking the function that is only usable if the owner is the caller, This fails with anywhere from 10 to 200 Gwei:

```
function OwnerWithdraw(uint256 _amountToDraw) public onlyOwner {        
   
    payable(owner).transfer(_amountToDraw);

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check the value of `owner` on the mainnet, and the sender of the transaction. Are they the same?

Comment: Just a small update on this:

The function (above) works on ETH Ropsen, and another Ethereum clone chain... but fails on ETC mainnet

What i find confusing is how the EVM on these chains is working? is this a gas problem or an EVM difference?

Comment: Hi @PetrHejda, thanks for the comment. Yes i was invoking the function as owner, as the modifier is :

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

Answer (score 0):

Ok so, the answer to this question was simple, I tested a modified version of the code on Ropsten and ETC main net. Turns out my gas limit for running these functions was set too low on ETC main net.